# Update a file in C

Tags: c, string, file-handling

I have a file (I created via file handling) in C, there are two functions add(), update().
1. add(): Adds an entry to the file i form of text which I then write into the file and save it.
2. update(): Here is the problem, I'm trying to update the already existing file contents but what happens is the file contents get vanished and whatever I write on the console gets written onto the file, all previous data lost.

So is there any way to get that already written file content on console screen when I call the update() function and then edit the content instead of what is happening.

Here is the code.

```
void add_diary(unsigned dd, unsigned mm, unsigned yy) {
    yy = 17;
    long file_extra;
    char file_name[50], c[50000];
    FILE *fptr;
    file_extra = (((dd*100)+mm)*100)+yy;
    sprintf(file_name, "diary%ld.txt", file_extra);
    fptr = fopen(file_name, "w");
    printf("\nStart writing diary..\n");
    fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
    fprintf(fptr,"%s",c);
    fclose(fptr);
    diary_login();
}


void update_entry(unsigned dd, unsigned mm, unsigned yy) {
    long file_extra;
    yy = 17;
    char file_name[50], c[50000];
    file_extra = (((dd*100)+mm)*100)+yy;
    sprintf(file_name, "diary%ld.txt", file_extra);
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen(file_name, "w+");
    printf("\nStart editing diary..\n");
    fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
    fprintf(fptr,"%s",c);
    fclose(fptr);
    diary_login();
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do? Are you trying to read the whole file in, modify the contents in memory, and then overwrite the entire file with the modified contents?

Comment: If you want to append to the file, you can open it with `fopen(file_name, "a");`.  When you open with "w+", you'll be overwriting whatever was in the file.

Comment: I want to get whatever I already wrote and saved in a file via add_diary() and then when I open the same file via update_entry(), the content I wrote  via add_diary() must be there plus more to be added.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, that only helped in fixing half of the problem, i can now add contents to file but what if I wanted to edit the already written content?

Comment: There's one more thing how can I save and retrieve password efficiently via file handling.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append to the file, you can open it with `fopen(file_name, "a");`. When you open with `"w+"`, you'll be overwriting whatever was in the file.

If you want to "edit" the file, you need to define what you mean by "edit".  A file is just a sequence of bytes, so if you open the file with `"wb+"`, you can overwrite any or all bytes in the file.  You can use `fseek` to change the write position to any specific point, then use `fwrite` to write bytes at that point, overwriting whatever was is those bytes or extended the file file if you're writing past the end.  There's no way to move bytes in a file, other than reading them from one place and writing them somewhere else.

Note that I say "bytes" rather than "characters" -- that's why you also need to use `"b"` and `fwrite` to get precise control over this.  Without binary mode, there may be various translations of characters (inserting or removing carriage returns, converting between various unicode encodings) that may occur.